# How to maximize subset accuracy for multilabel multiclass image classification

Tags: neural-networks, classification, tensorflow, multi-class, multilabel

I working on multi-label multi-class image classification. I am using TensorFlow.
Currently I am using sigmoid on output layer with `binary_crossentrpy`. Model is giving fair accuracy, but for my requirement I need to rely on Subset accuracy (exact match) and not overall accuracy. For evaluation purpose I am using Subset Accuracy metric, but model is obviously maximizing overall accuracy. How can I add a custom loss function so that I can maximize subset accuracy.

Comment: You mean for a specific subset or the subset accuracy for all subsets?

Comment: @Janosch Look for [Exact Match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification#Statistics_and_evaluation_metrics) aka subset accuracy. Currently I am calculating subset accuracy for my test set.